# Why isn't ng-class working?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-class

I want to highlight currently selected menu item with AngularJS. 
I have this HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="m in menuLinks">
    <a ng-class="{active : isActive('{{m.url}}')}" href="{{m.url}}" active-link="active" onclick="closeMenu()">{{m.title}}</a>
</li>
```

And this in the controller:

```
$scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) {
        alert(viewLocation);
        if ($location.path().indexOf(viewLocation) === 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
};
```

The function isActive() gets called because alerts show up, but when I inspect the elements I get this:

```
<a class="ng-binding" ng-class="{active : isActive('/#/sessions')}" href="/#/sessions" active-link="active" onclick="closeMenu()">Sessions</a>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the expression in `ng-class`, just use it like this:

```
 <a ng-class="{active : isActive(m.url)}" ng-href="{{m.url}}" active-link="active" ng-click="closeMenu()">{{m.title}}</a>
```

and I recommend using `ng-href` instead of just href and `ng-click` instead of onclick ;)

Answer (score 1):

$location.path() does not return an array, whereas indexOf searches the index of the item in an array.

Comment: Strings has `indexOf()` function, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp